# Apache Camel custom Producer setup question

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to configure the Apache Camel Producer component (generated by camel-archetype-component archetype) and have a question on how one of the parts works.

Code for the Endpoint:

```
@UriEndpoint(firstVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT", scheme = "xmlGenerator", title = "xmlGenerator", syntax = "xmlGenerator:testScope",
        category = {Category.JAVA, Category.CORE})
public class xmlGeneratorEndpoint extends DefaultEndpoint {

    @UriPath
    @Metadata(required = true)
    private String testScope;
```

my question is, the "testScope" is never used. the default setup has the setter/getter but neither is called.

using `.to("xmlGenerator://hello?option=12")` the "testScope" variable is never set.
even using `.to("xmlGenerator://?option=12")` does not cause issues. Id assume it should.

how do I get it to set that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue with the help of looking at the google-bigquery component (thanks Claus).

the main part is you need to implement a

```
public class ProducerContractConfiguration implements Cloneable {
    // this is where you put your path variables (obj://__TheseValues:moreValues)
}
```

in your EndPoint class add the following setup:

```
    @UriParam
    protected final ProducerContractConfiguration configuration;

    public ProducerContractEndpoint(String uri, ProducerContractComponent component, ProducerContractConfiguration configuration) {
        super(uri, component);
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }


    /**
     * Note, this seems to be needed for Mojo to not yell at you. 
     * @return
     */
    public ProducerContractConfiguration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }
```

also found that if you run into build issues, clean up the "generated" folder then run maven command again.

Answer (score 1):

Its the component that is responsible for setting that, you need to add that in the component source code. You need to do that for all options that are marked with `UriPath`. Options marked with `UriParam` can be automatic mapped in bulk from the component via `setProperties...`.

But take a look at one of the existing components source code to better understand.

There is also some docs at: https://camel.apache.org/manual/writing-components.html

And if you have the CiA2 book it has a chapter/section on writing custom components.